# click a button to retrieve a highlighted word from a text area

Tags: javascript

In a simple webapp, I have a text area with some text, when user highligh a word in the text area, then click a button to process the word, the handler failed to get the highlighted word.

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="handle()"><input>
<textarea> </textarea>
<script>
function handle() {
alert(window.getSelection().toString());
}
</script>
```

Any idea how to do this?
Thanks

**UPDATE1**

When I run `window.getSelection().toString()` in Chrome developer console, it does give the highlighted text, however, when I click a button. it returned nothing. I guess clicking will de-highlight the highlighted text.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058048/how-to-get-selected-text-inside-a-textarea-element-by-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @galactocalypse for the links.  Just updated my question, the issue seems to be, clicking the button will de-highlight the text, defeating the purpose.

Comment: Even with the de-highlight, the selection remains selected. You should get the values anyway. I just tried this on FF and it worked.

Comment: When I tried it on my Chrome,  `window.getSelection()` when lose its value when clicking another button, but I `textareaObj.selectionStart, textareaObj.selectionEnd` will retain the value when clicking on a  button. So I came up with a solution using it.  Thanks again for trying and the good info that it works fine on FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the button as you say will deselect the text. One work around could be this:

1. Bind a mouseup up event and store the highlited if there is. Here is some reference: [Selected text event trigger in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript)
2. When you click the button you can use the stored text.

Right now I'm on my phone, but when I get access to a pc I can provide some code.

Here is some reference also for preventing the highlited text to be lost: [Any way to prevent "deselection" of highlighted text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486414/any-way-to-prevent-deselection-of-highlighted-text)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting links.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try this -

> window.(textareaID).getselection().tostring

Create textareaID:

```
<textarea id="*your id here*><\textarea>
```