# HTML textbox input- Always select all text on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I achieve the following behavior in an html text input: when a user clicks the input, all the text will be selected, even if it's already selected. Thus there won't be any possibility to delete/select certain characters.

currently I have the following:

```js
elm.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).select();
});
```

but if the text is selected then a click displays a carret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a fun one!

The trick is not to `preventDefault()` on the `click` event, but instead the `mouseDown` event.

```
$('#clickme').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).select();
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cs7qojt/) and the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486414/any-way-to-prevent-deselection-of-highlighted-text) I got the answer from

Comment: Have you tried this on a mobile device? To select it in Chrome for Android, you have to tap the input, then tap away from the input, then tap it again.

Answer (score 1):

> Thus there won't be any possibility to delete/select certain characters.

For this, I recommend using `readonly` on your input:

```
<input readonly type="text" ...
```

Also, if you remove `e.preventDefault()` it will continue to stay selected.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dgryhdtL/

## Update

Sometimes when you click selected text, it will de-select. To get around that, you need to create a small delay:

```
var that = $(this);
setTimeout(function(){
  that.select();
}, 100);
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dgryhdtL/1/

Comment: tnx that was great, but the timeout seems as a code smell, so I went with willcwf's answer

Comment: @NirSmadar his code doesn't work for me on Chrome for Android.

Comment: @rybo1114 tnx, i dont need mobile support

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code:

```
$("input[type='text']").on("click", function () {
    //select the text in text field
    $(this).select();
});
```

**Edit:**
If you have your element already in **elm** variable than you do not need to write jQuery selector. You can use:

```
elm.on("click", function () {
    //select the text in text field
    $(this).select();
});
```

Comment: He already has that code. `elm` will be the element he has selected in a previous line.

Comment: OK? You haven't contributed anything to the code in the first post.

Comment: Your answer and subsequent edits make no attempt to answer the question. Read the question. It has nothing to do with how to select the element.